# How do I search a folder in file explorer regardless of the spelling (ignore spaces)

Tags: windows-explorer, search, spell-check, personal-data

I have a folder named for example **DDC77** but I want the file explorer to return me that exact folder even if I search **D DCC77** or **DD C77**

Answer (score 1):

Explorer doesn't do partial strings. You will need to use wildcards,
like this : `DD*C77`.

For a more flexible file-search product, see the free
[voidtools Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/),
which is also *much* faster and more flexible than Explorer.

Comment: [Malware is actively exploiting Everything](https://www.trendmicro.com/en_us/research/23/a/new-mimic-ransomware-abuses-everything-apis-for-its-encryption-p.html)

Comment: @Ramhound That just means that the malware is using that particular piece of software, not that the software itself is bad, right? I am not sure what the point of your comment is. I could easily write a bit of malware that uses WebBrowserPassView, or even normal Windows DLLs to use the functionality provided. But that doesn't mean WebBrowserPassView or those Windows DLLs are "bad".

Comment: As long as the software is downloaded from the voidtools website this is safe.